# Don't hide OverlayPanel on click

Tags: jquery, jsf, primefaces

I would like to make PrimeFaces [Overlay Panel](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase-labs/ui/overlayPanel.jsf) to stay visible even if user has clicked area outside the tooltip. The only way to close the tooltip would be Close button on it.

How can it be done?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Im not jquery/javascript expert, there colud be more elegant solutions.

```
<p:commandButton id="chartBtn" value="Basic" type="button" /> 
<p:overlayPanel id="chartPanel" widgetVar="chartPanelWidget" for="chartBtn" hideEffect="fade"
                                    onShow="$(document.body).unbind('mousedown.ui-overlay')">  
   <p:commandButton value="close" onclick="chartPanelWidhget.hide();return false;"/>
</p:overlayPanel>
```

Comment: This jQuery disables the mousedown reaction for all overlays on the page. Can be unwanted if you have more overlays and do not wish this behavior for all overlays.

Comment: @alex.parej how did you found out that it was firing `mousedown.ui-overlay` event? please tell me!!

Answer (score 10):

If you use Primefaces 4-SNAPSHOT there is a attribute called dismissable. When you set it to false, the overlay can only be closed by clicking on the button again.

Comment: And also you can add showCloseIcon="true" to show the close button on PrimeFaces 5.*